# T2022 Transfer fees swap?

Tags: spl-token, transfer, fees, token-2022

I've been interested in Solana's ecosystem recently and digged a lot of documentation.

While going through token-2022 docs I found out that the transfer fees that occur on **ALL** transfers are like a deducted tax.

***My question is :***

*Is there a way to modify the function in order to swap(or maybe through the transfer-hook function) so that the withdrawer wallet doesn't receive native token but SOL or wSOL ?*

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, the transfer fees in token-2022 are only denominated in the same token. If you want to deduct a transfer fee in a different token, then you will need to do this separately through a transfer-hook.

Note that there are protections in token-2022 which demote the authorizing signer to be a non-signer to avoid abuse in transfer-hook programs, so you'll need to pass in additional signers if you want to go this path.