# How to pass a signer through to custom Transfer Hook program?

Tags: spl-token, token-2022, token-extensions

When sending a transferChecked transaction with the transfer hook extension enabled, it seems that a custom transfer hook program fails to receive the signers from the Token 2022 program when it CPIs into the custom transfer hook program.

For example, [this token account owner](https://github.com/ZYJLiu/anchor-transfer-hook/blob/counter/programs/transfer-hook/src/lib.rs#L85) always returns false for `ctx.accounts.owner.is_signer`, even though it signs for the token transfer.

From the answer to this [question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/t2022-transfer-fees-swap), it seems like this is the intended behavior.

> Note that there are protections in token-2022 which demote the
> authorizing signer to be a non-signer to avoid abuse in transfer-hook
> programs, so you'll need to pass in additional signers if you want to
> go this path.

However, how can I pass in additional signer to the transaction so that signers don't get dropped during the CPI?